# Calling function from within Knockout Observable Array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a Knockout observable array that I wish to edit from within Javascript and from the HTML as well. Here is my code:

```
var ListModel = function(formula) {
  var self = this;
  self.formula = ko.observableArray(formula);

  this.mergeEquation = function(op) {
    if (op.type == "ins") {
      self.formula.splice(op.position, 0, op.value);
    } else if (op.type == "del") {
      self.formula.splice(op.position, 1);
    } else {
      console.info("No match: " + op.value + op.position);
    }
  };
};
```

My variable `op` is a JSON string. I know how to call the `mergeEquation` function using HTML data-bind, but how do I do so from within the same JS file? My current code goes something like this:

```
ko.applyBindings(new ListModel(formula));
//...
//initializing of JSON object called op
//...
if (something) {
  mergeEquation(op);
}
```

but it doesn't work. Am I missing out some step here? I've read up on [functions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html) and [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) but both seems too overkill for what I'm trying to do here.

PS: Here's a sample of the JSON structure I'm working with:

```
{"type":"ins", "clientID":1223, "version":0, "value":"hi", "position":0, "id":2736}
```

Comment: you need to show the part where you create the ListModel, and where you try to call mergeEquation in relation to it :)

Comment: Oh right. I'll edit my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change :-

```
ko.applyBindings(new ListModel(formula));
```

to

```
  var vm = new ListModel(formula);
   ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

so, now vm is the thing you can call the mergeequation on

```
vm.mergeEquation(op)
```